# ld cannot find -lgfortran

Tags: arch-linux, make, libraries, cmake

I'm trying to compile [Knut](https://github.com/rs1909/knut) (a maths program) on Arch Linux with CMake and I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cli/CMakeFiles/knut-cli.dir/build.make:101: cli/knut-cli] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:498: cli/CMakeFiles/knut-cli.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

I believe both`gfortran` and `quadmath` are installed, and the links seem to be correct as well:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib | grep "fortran"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Jun  3 23:11 libgfortran.so -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Jun  3 23:11 libgfortran.so.3 -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  5858448 Jun  3 23:11 libgfortran.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      269 Jun  3 03:11 libgfortran.spec

$ ls -al /usr/lib | grep "libquadmath"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Jun  3 23:11 libquadmath.so -> libquadmath.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Jun  3 23:11 libquadmath.so.0 -> libquadmath.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   958384 Jun  3 23:11 libquadmath.so.0.0.0
```

The same .so files are also found in `/usr/lib64`.

I have gfortran version 6.1.1. I don't know much CMake so the only thing I tried to change in the cmake command is to add `-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib`, which didn't help.

Any suggestions how I could proceed to find the problem?

**EDIT1**

I've run `cmake` without the subsequent `make` and it seems all dependencies are met:

```
- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.1.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.1.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 6.1.1
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- The shell is found: /usr/bin/sh
-- The C++ runtime library is /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-  gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/libstdc++.a
-- The FORTRAN runtime library is libgfortran.a, /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/libgcc.a and libquadmath.a
-- The DYNAMIC FORTRAN runtime library is /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib/libgfortran.so
-- openBLAS was found as /usr/lib64/libopenblas.so.
-- Using system UMFPACK and AMD: /usr/lib64/libumfpack.so and /usr/lib64/libamd.so.
-- The includes are at /usr/include and /usr/include.
-- Using system LAPACK and ARPACK /usr/lib64/liblapack.so;/usr/lib64/libarpack.so.
-- The mxml library is /usr/lib64/libmxml.so.
-- The mxml include directory is /usr/include.
-- --> Qt5Core found.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mark/knut/knut/build
```

The aforementioned errors occur when I subsequently run `make`.

**EDIT2**

I've noticed that my /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/ does not contain the static libraries `libgfortran.a` and `libquadmath.a`. I have `gcc-4.8.5` on another computer and there these files exist. From the `cmake` output these are the two libraries that are not found it seems, since there is no path given for them.

Now I'm not sure what that means, whether that's a problem with my gfortran installation or something else?

**EDIT3 June 24**

The problem with libgfortran seems to be Arch specific. Apparently static libraries are usually not packaged in Arch. That's why the same gcc-fortran package in Debian contains files libgfortran.a and libquadmath.a but not in Arch. I've changed the options in PKGBUILD to `options=('staticlibs')` to include the static libraries for the next compilation (using [abs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System)). Then I copied the generated libgfortran.a and libquadmath.a files into `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/` and the problem with libgfortran seems to be solved.

However, I'm getting now the Qt5 error mentioned by Knud Larsen.

Comment: Did you run `cmake`, *then* install `gfortran`? If so, you need to rerun `cmake` (remove its `CMakeCache.txt` first).

Comment: I had `gfortran` before running `cmake` but I also clean the `build` directory after every try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

https://github.com/rs1909/knut/tree/master/knut

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath

Please read knut/knut/knut.spec.cmake → Buildrequires: libgfortran-static .... i.e. libgfortran.**a**

Probably the same for -lquadmath : libquadmath.a

( I get no errors with the cmake configuring : The Makefile is created.)

---

EDIT 1, 23 June : The above appears to be a configuring example only : The Makefile was created.

Build example(s) : PCLinuxOS 2016, CentOS 7, Fedora 24 are failing with Qt5 errors.

- Debian 8 Jessie : No issues, except for a cmake generated syntax error in `knut/knut/build/src/config.h` .  $ `make` and # `make install` are OK.
  The gfortran, g++ are version 4.9.2 . "libgfortran-4.9-dev" provides libgfortran.a, libquadmath.a

---

EDIT 2, June 23 : A build with Ubuntu 16.04 ... to try out a later compiler, gcc-5.3.1 ...

```
cd knut/knut/build/ && CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 FC=gfortran-5 cmake .. && make && sudo make install
```

- No issues ....

---

EDIT 3 : Testing knut with gcc/g++/gfortran version **6.1.1** → Debian 9 Stretch.

```
CC=gcc-6 CXX=g++-6 FC=gfortran-6 cmake .. && make ; # make install
```

- Is also OK.

EDIT 4 : Build requirements .. # `apt-get install g++ libopenblas-dev libqt5svg5-dev`

The conclusion I can have from all the above is that the used Qt5 must fit. May be there's difference in the Qt5 configuration ? patching ? ... I don't find any important difference in the Qt5 file locations.

[knut](/questions/tagged/knut)

Comment: Would you mind sharing your distro and gcc/fortran version?

Comment: »» Would you mind sharing .. «« : Yes, when I find the OS ... I used that day. I.e. I have all the mainstream OS´s / all versions. ( Currently no Arch Linux.)

Comment: OK, I gave up trying to fix the qt5 error in Arch. But even in Ubuntu 16.04, with gcc-5.3.1, I'm getting the qt5 error. qtbase5-dev should be enough right? Or did you use any different qt5 package? Many thanks by the way!

Comment: Debian Stretch, Ubuntu 16.04 : # `apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev` ... will do for all the Qt5 . See the edited post : Build requirements.